# What makes WCF Test Client show up in WCF > WCF Service Application but not ASP.NET Web Application projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

Enviroment: Visual Studio 2010 SP1

My goal of course is to use it in an existing app by knowing how to turn it on as needed. I realize you can just open in manually.

WCF Service Application
[image: WCF Service Application]
ASP.NET Web Aplication Project
[image: ASP.NET Web Aplication Project]
WCF Test Client
[image: WCF Test Client]

Comment: Are you asking how Visual Studio categorizes it's project templates?

Comment: No. Why does the test client show up when the Wcf project is ran  but not the other.

Comment: I really think you need to make another attempt at asking this question.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it.  So, are you asking why you don't see the web application in the WCF Test client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*WCF Service Application* project is a flavoured project in terms of Visual Studio. This means that additional logic is attached to a common generic C# project. Project flavour is defined at the corresponding .csproj file by *ProjectTypeGuids* XML tag. Here is what you may see for a C# WCF Service Application if you open it with a text editor:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

If you want to make some other C# project to become a *WCF Service Application* one, just copy that string to corresponding .csproj file. You may also need to consider ProjectExtensions / VisualStudio / FlavorProperties / WebProjectProperties XML section and copy it too for the sake of behavioral equality:

```
<ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>51329</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>
          </IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
          <EnableWcfTestClientForSVCDefaultValue>True</EnableWcfTestClientForSVCDefaultValue>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a post build events if you want to open the WCF test client from you ASP.NET web applications project

You can add this "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe" http://xyz.svc in the post build events in the compile tab of your Project Properties page.

Answer (score 2):

Open the project file with a Text Editor
Find the below Line and remove it

```
<EnableWcfTestClientForSVCDefaultValue>True</EnableWcfTestClientForSVCDefaultValue>
```

If the project is already opened in Visual Studio, it will ask for Reloading. Do it and Run.
Otherwise just open the project and Run again.

Answer (score 0):

The web application project runs in visual studio's cassini host (like a very cut down version of IIS), so your WCF service will be open at http://localhost:9999/MyServiceName.svc where 9999 will actually be a random number.  You can set this to a fixed value of your choosing in the project properties Web tab.